# How to print single quotes in twig template?

Tags: symfony, twig

I need to assign a variable which contains single quote.

In php I would do:

```
$hello='testing \' quotes ';
```

What is the twig equivalent code for printing quotes?

Comment: Why don't you use double quotes? `{% set hello = "'" %}`

Comment: i can't use it like that

Comment: In case if Twig does not allow escaping, which is strange, you can try this: `{% set hello %}'{% endset %}`

Comment: I have openend [an issues](https://github.com/fabpot/Twig/issues/973) because I think this should be implemented in Twig, otherwise it is really strange that you can't use double quotes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the same since twig templates are converted to php anyway

```
{{ 'some string \' with a single quote in it' }}
{% set value = 'the quote is here ->\'<-' %} {{ value }}
```