# Escaping simple quote in TWIG

Tags: xpath, twig, escaping

I'm using this TWIG query:

```
{% if xpath('md_file','//Archive/DOSSIER_MDPH[contains("#FILENAME#", Identifiant)]') %}{{ xpath('md_file','//Archive/DOSSIER_MDPH[contains("#FILENAME#", Identifiant)]/Personne/LIBLDOMA') }} {% endif %}
```

Sometimes the value of #FILENAME# includes the ' character (simple quote). When this is the case, I get an error indicating that the request is badly formed.
For exemple :

```
1. {% if xpath('md_file','//Archive/DOSSIER[contains("08 - Fiche d'option.pdf", Identifiant)]') %}{{ xpath('md_file','//Archive/DOSSIER[contains("08 - Fiche d'option.pdf", Identifiant)]/Personne/LIBLDOMA') }} {% endif %}^^^ Unexpected "}"
```

How do you escape the simple quote? I've tried adding an \ before the #FILENAME# but it doesn't work. I've also tried replacing the " with '.

Comment: *"Sometimes the value of #FILENAME# includes the ' character*" - What does this mean? `#FILENAME#` is just a literal string, how could it include the `'` character? Please give enough explanation.  `xpath` is not a default function inside twig so we don't have a clue what it actually does.

Comment: FYI: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14464384/how-to-print-single-quotes-in-twig-template

Comment: @DarkBee, I'm sorry, but #FILENAME# is a variable that contains random file names. It is not a constant string.
So sometimes, the value of #FILENAME# may contain a quote. In my example, #FILENAME# was filled with "08 - Option sheet.pdf". Thanks

Comment: "*I get an error indicating that the request*" - Can you please post the full error (with stacktrace) as well? Then we have an indication where the actual error is thrown.

Comment: @DarkBee, I use an application that uses Twig to configure operations. So I don't have access to complete errors. The error I have:  Unexpected "}".

1. {% if xpath('md_file','//Archive/DOSSIER[contains("08 - Fiche d'option.pdf", Identifiant)]') %}{{ xpath('md_file','//Archive/DOSSIER[contains("08 - Fiche d'option.pdf", Identifiant)]/Personne/LIBLDOMA') }} {% endif %}^^^ Unexpected "}". Thanks.

Comment: Cant [reproduce](https://twigfiddle.com/eqb4ln)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution:

```
{% set escapedFilename = "#FILENAME#"|escape %}
{% if xpath('md_file', '//Archive/DOSSIER[contains("' ~ escapedFilename ~ '", Identifiant)]') %}
Name: {{ xpath('md_file', '//Archive/DOSSIER[contains("' ~ escapedFilename ~ '", Identifier)]/Personne/LIBLDOMA') }}{% endif %}
```